# How To Provide Database Independency in JDBC Without Using Hibernate.?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to solve this problem with the help of properties file, but in a Properties file, we can handle only Database Driver problem. If I want to switch my MySQL to Oracle database I need to change my all query. The problem is how to make query independent in JDBC?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DBIndependencyExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties pros = new Properties();
            InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                    "D:\\Programs\\Eclipse\\DBIndependecyByPropertiesFile\\src\\connectdb.properties");
            pros.load(fis);
            String Drivername = pros.getProperty("k1");
            //System.out.println(Drivername);
            String url = pros.getProperty("k2");
            String un = pros.getProperty("k3");
            String pw = pros.getProperty("k4");
            Class.forName(Drivername);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, pw);
            System.out.println("Driver Is Loaded With" + Drivername);
            System.out.println("Connection is Opened");
            Statement smt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = pros.getProperty("k5");
            //System.out.println(sql);
            ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("username is:" + rs.getString(1) + " password is:" + rs.getString(2));
            }
            con.close();
            System.out.println("Connection is closed");
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Properties File:

```
//Mysql Connectivity 
//Start Properties File Code
k1=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
k2=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practice
k3=root
k4=root
k5=select * from student

//Oracle  Connectivity

k1=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
k2=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcla
k3=scott
k4=manish       
k5=select * from dept
```

Comment: `select * from student` and `select * from dept` should work on both Oracle and MySQL; do you have more complex queries that don't work with both RDBMS?

Comment: There are some specific query based on mysql and oracle.suppose my application is based on mysql db and i want to change my db to any other db.in that case i have to change the whole query what we applied in our application.i need something that can accept any database query in my application.thanks

Comment: I don't think there exists an utility that would automatically translate proprietary syntax from one vendor to another. As others have pointed out, you either need to stick to ANSI SQL syntax or then you need separate queries for different databases.

Answer (score 1):

> If i want to switch my mysql to oracle database i need to change my
>   all query.

If your SQL queries rely only on the ANSI SQL and never on proprietary specificites (function, keywords, and...) you should be able to switch from an DBMS to another one without any change in the queries.
Note that Hibernate will not translate for a DBMS specifities to another one as for example translate a query on the DUAL table written in Oracle to a MySQL way.
Hibernate ensures that your SQL queries be portable while you don't create native queries, a possibility still provided by Hibernate.

[Here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) is the original SQL ANSI draft and [here](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c053681_ISO_IEC_9075-1_2011.zip) a download link for the last version of Information technology -- Database languages -- SQL -- Part 1: Framework (SQL/Framework)

Comment: Sir there is any other way where i can execute all the query of mysql and oracle.

Comment: @Manish There is not a miracle way, sorry.

Comment: Thanks For Your Valuable Time.

Comment: Problem is: average MySQL code from average MySQL programmer from golden years of LAMP is totally nonportable. SQL queries must be serious disciplined to SQL ANSI

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so if you switch to hibernate or any orm frameworks. In case of hibernate you can use hql to write the queries in that way you are database independent no matter what database you switch hibernate will take care. You can even look at Spring CrudRepository. I highly doubtful you can achieve database independent queries just with the JDBC. It is good to begin with JDBC for a long run you should consider orm frameworks.

Comment: Dear Sir, I know we can achieve database in-dependency with the help of hibernate ORM tool but my requirement is i want to do database in-dependency with the help of JDBC.

Comment: If there are no third party api then you have to write your implementation to convert the queries based on your property file change before executing your statement.executeQuery you can change your query according to your database. If this is just for a method it's fine but you wanna do for the whole application suggest your team to move towards orm. These are one of main reason they introduced orm.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic method that can handle any sql query (regardless of the database used). The trick here is to use database metadata to automatically
populate a hash map (a hash map is convenient because we can use the column names as keys) containing the query results. For parameterized queries, you'll need a more complex method, which can be found at the link provided below (`DBSelect.getRecordsForCustomQuery`). If all your queries targeting different databases are the same, then you don't even have to use metadata, just hardcode the column names.

```
public Map<String, Object> getQueryResults(String query, Connection conn){

    ResultSet rs=null; 
    PreparedStatement stmt=null; 
    Map<String, Object> objMap = new HashMap<>();

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery); 
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    for (int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++) { 
                objMap.put( rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i)); 
    }
 }
    return mapObj;

}
```

You can, of course, modify this method to suit your needs.

A slightly  more elaborate solution which uses reflection and generics can be found here ( https://github.com/IvanGH2/EasyORM ) but you don't 
even have to use all of that.