# How to use the same Java class with different SQL queries

Tags: java, sql, class, generics, mapping

I'm designing a Java report application that can receive any SQL query(on a already defined database) and then I display the result in a table grid in a Vue.js application.

I have some doubts on how to load a Java generic/hybrid class that can fit differents SQL queries.

I mean, is it possible to create a class in Java that can change/mutate during runtime so I can map different SQL queries in it?

I know that it is possible to use the java.sql.ResultSetMetaData to get the column name, table name, column class name, etc. (I don't know if it possible with hibernate)
But I don't know how to map the results in a unique class.

For example:

I have 3 differents queries and they could be a lot more:

```
1) SELECT ID, COUNTRY_NAME FROM COUNTRY;

2) SELECT CODE, NAME, PRICE FROM PRODUCT;

3) SELECT P.CODE, P.NAME, S.NAME 
     FROM PRODUCT P
     JOIN SUPPLIER S
       ON S.ID = P.SUPPLIER_ID
     WHERE P.PRICE > 25;
```

I need to map this query results(one at a time obviously) in a generic class so then I pass it to the Vue app to display it in a grid.

Is it a way to do that?

Comment: What advantage do you want to achieve having such class?

Comment: What people usualy do is to have a SqlUtil class somewhere on the classpath that has a bunch of static methods that return ResultSets (or other type of collections). My favorite is a method that takes a String and executes the SQL that was in the String.

Comment: @Tom I want to generate different reports quickly without mapping all the tables. So I pass any SQL query and then the query result is load in a grid in a Vue.js app. May be I'm thinking the wrong solution and it is quiet simple with other way. I'm open to any correction or solution.

Comment: @Mike Jensens, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892329/how-to-provide-database-independency-in-jdbc-without-using-hibernate/49899622#49899622. This example will show you how to get data for any sql query but you will still need to populate your Java class. Note that you can't have only one class to achieve this (and it would make for horrible design if you did)

Comment: Thanks! But finally I changed the solution I had thought. I will convert the sql query result directly to json format to pass it to the table grid in the Vue app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use what is already available and what is well tested.
What you're looking for is called `Spring JDBC`, or, for an even higher level, `Java Persistence API`.

Using `Spring JDBC` to extract a set of records might look like

```
final List<YourClass> results =
          jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
                   "Native SQL statement",
                   queryArguments,
                   YourClass.class
          );
```

Using a `JPA` implementation (e.g. `Hibernate`, `EclipseLink`, `ObjectDb`), the operation might look like

```
final TypedQuery<YourClass> query = entityManager.createQuery("JPQL statement", YourClass.class);
final List<YourClass> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank for the answer! The only problem is that there will be a lot of different queries of different tables or combination of tables(with joins) and MyClass is only one class and have to fit any result. That's my main doubt.

Comment: @MikeJensens than, for example, `Spring JDBC` offers a `queryForList` method, which will return a `List<Map<String, Object>>` representing the entire `ResultSet` as key-value pairs (columnName-columnValue).

Comment: @MikeJensens TLDR you cannot have a *dynamic* Java class, as its structure must be known at compile time.